# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP, The method is undefined

Tags: java, spring, wcf, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a project with Netbeans 7.4/Jdk7/Tomcat7.

Project uses Spring framework in front and soap WCF service in backend. There is a problem with one method in service, that I declare. I can get this method in spring without any compilation errors, but when I try to run the project it throws exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
>     An error occurred at line: 30 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsp/include/page_header.jsp 
>    The method isIsPosUser() is undefined for the type UserInfo

My UserInfo class:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("user_info")]
[DataContract(Name = "user_info", Namespace = "urn:...")]
public class UserInfo
{
    private String _FullName;
    private String _EMail;
    private bool _IsPosUser;

    public UserInfo(string pFullName, 
                    string pEmail)
    {
        FullName = pFullName;
        EMail = pEmail;
    }

    public UserInfo()
    {
        //dummy
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "full_name")]
    [DataMember(Name = "full_name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return _FullName; }
        set { _FullName = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "e_mail")]
    [DataMember(Name = "e_mail")]
    public string EMail
    {
        get { return _EMail; }
        set { _EMail = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsPosUser")]
    [DataMember(Name = "IsPosUser")]
    public bool IsPosUser
    {
        get { return _IsPosUser; }
        set { _IsPosUser = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("FullName: {0}, EMail: {1}, IsPosUser: {2}", FullName, EMail, IsPosUser);
    }
}
```

Generated source code of imported wsdl in spring app:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UserInfo", propOrder = {
"fullName",
"eMail",
"isPosUser"
})
public class UserInfo {

@XmlElement(name = "full_name")
protected String fullName;
@XmlElement(name = "e_mail")
protected String eMail;
@XmlElement(name = "IsPosUser")
protected boolean isPosUser;


/**
 * Gets the value of the fullName property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the fullName property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setFullName(String value) {
    this.fullName = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the eMail property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getEMail() {
    return eMail;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the eMail property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setEMail(String value) {
    this.eMail = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the isPosUser property.
 * 
 */
public boolean isIsPosUser() {
    return isPosUser;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the isPosUser property.
 * 
 */
public void setIsPosUser(boolean value) {
    this.isPosUser = value;
}

}
```

And I try to get this value in jsp file after authentication:

```
<%
    SoapUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken retVal = (SoapUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserInfo userInfo = retVal.getUserInfo();
    boolean isPosUser = userInfo.isIsPosUser();
%>
```

It throws exception here. If I remove this method call from my spring application, everything works fine. The problem is in userInfo.isIsPosUser(); but cannot figure out what is the cause.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you have missed typed isPosUser() in the scriplet

```
boolean isPosUser = userInfo.IsPosUser();
```

instead of:

```
boolean isPosUser = userInfo.isIsPosUser();
```

Comment: I got compile error, if I try to write userInfo.isPosUser() instead of userInfo.isIsPosUser(). Because the method in autogenerated file is:

/**
 * Gets the value of the isPosUser property.
 * 
 */
public boolean isIsPosUser() {
    return isPosUser;
}

Comment: userInfo.IsPosUser(); first letter with uppercase

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method IsPosUser()
  location: variable userInfo of type UserInfo

Comment: why do you have this getter named like this

/**
 * Gets the value of the isPosUser property.
 * 
 */
public boolean isIsPosUser() {
    return isPosUser;
}

Comment: public boolean isIsPosUser(); change too: public boolean isPosUser() ;

Comment: yeap, ur right, if I change manually the method boolean isIsPosUser() to boolean isPosUser() it works. But if I make clean and rebuild my spring application in netbeans it generates that wsdl import file again and the name becomes boolean isIsPosUser(). Cannot figure out what is the reason

Comment: in your UserInfo class: [XmlElement(ElementName = "IsPosUser")]
    [DataMember(Name = "IsPosUser")]
    public bool IsPosUser
    {
       ...
    }

try and change the signature from "public bool IsPosUser" to: "public bool PosUser", because I think the frameworks appends an extra "is" because of the returned type :)

Comment: :) I know it, i cannot understand why it does not work with double leading "is" (isIsPosUser())

Comment: It does not work again. I changed then name of the method in service to @XmlElement(name = "PosUser")
        protected boolean posUser;

<br />
public boolean isPosUser() {
        return posUser;
    }

It works only if i remove the leading is from isPosUser() in generated import file. netbeans generates wrong files ..!!

Comment: try change in your class [DataMember(Name = "IsPosUser")] to [DataMember(Name = "posUser")]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68390/discussion-between-0bj3ct-and-aurelius).